# Dependency Injection in c# class Library

Tags: c#, singleton

Actually I am facing a problem related to add to my c# project,
I have a class library project that contains a AzureWebJob Function, 
this function contains a lot object references like, httpclient 
or IRepository, but in order to create a new instance of the client or some repository or any other object instance,
I would like be able to get the current instance, as a singleton. 
I have experience using Structure map in order create that but in this case I do not have a start point in order to init all the object that I will use in the functions and get the instances to be used, 
is there a way to do that?

Actually I have this code in order to create a new instance of

```
 httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

I would like get the current instance

```
 httpClient = _instance?? new HttpClient();
```

Is there a way to init in the class library and inject the instance in the current context?

Comment: What Dependency Injection framework are you using? Prism or Spring.NET or Homemade?

Comment: hi @PrateekShrivastava I use StructureMap, but if this is nor possible I can use sprint.NET

Comment: I can speak from Spring.NET POV - In the Spring config you will have to create that ONE (Singleton) HttpClient instance. And then you can inject it (or DI framework will itself do so) via constructor/ property injection. I will check for StructureMap but it should be similar there.